# Appending a dataframe to an existing text file in Azure Storage using databricks notebooks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am trying to append a dataframe in databricks to a text file in Azure container.

I have no difficulties in file creation or appending std outputs/errors/custom logs to an existing file but i get errors when trying to convert a dataframe to string and append it to a text file as databricks is not supporting `df.to_string()`.

I have previously used `df.to_string` method in python scripts and it worked but with databricks, i am unable to do so. is there any other ways to do what i wanted?

```
import pandas as pd
logfile_test = '/dbfs/mnt/folderinAZcontainer/folder1/log/TestLog/test.txt'
testdata = {'name':['Amar','Akbar','Antony'],
            'empid':[1,2,3],
            'sal':[100,50,70]}
dftest = pd.DataFrame(testdata)
print(dftest)
with open(logfile_test, 'a') as f:
    f.write(dftest.to_string())
```

Error:

```
OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported
Command took 0.22 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be a [known limitation of Local File API](https://docs.databricks.com/en/files/index.html#local-file-api-limitations) - it's not listed explicitly for append operations, but it's a kind of "random write" operation that isn't supported because it’s not supported in underlying cloud APIs.

The workaround would be to copy file to the local file system, append to it, and copy back:

```py
logfile_test = '/mnt/folderinAZcontainer/folder1/log/TestLog/test.txt'
local_file = "/tmp/test.txt"
dbutils.fs.cp(logfile_test, "file:"+local_file)
with open(local_file, 'a') as f:
    f.write(dftest.to_string())
dbutils.fs.cp("file:"+local_file, logfile_test)
```

Comment: I tried the writing the df as a string to a new file in Azure storage and that is working but unable to append an already created file. @Alex Ott may it isn't supported.

Comment: yes, it's a limitation of underlying cloud API, so it's not supported